# how to add foreign key constraint, SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, foreign-keys

I have a registration table with primary key RegId. I have another table named Users, also contain RegId as Foreign key.

When I delete one RegId from registration, I have to delete RegId from Users. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

Define the foreign key with "ON DELETE CASCADE".

You can do this is [in T-SQL or in design view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177463(SQL.90).aspx) in SSMS

Answer (score 0):

You could to alter the main table with a constraint saying that a Delete On Cascade must be done.

Based on your inputs, something similar to this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Registration
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Registration_Users_Cascade
FOREIGN KEY (RegId) REFERENCES dbo.Users(RegId) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Also, you can achieve this with the SQL Management Studio selecting your table (in *Design* mode) and go to *Relationships* option. There you'll see the "INSERT and UPDATE specifications" button for setting this things.

MSDN Article

- [Cascading Referential Integrity Constraints](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973(v=sql.105).aspx)